# How do I fix my ffmpeg command to stop the Terminal from hanging?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am attempting to use `ffmpeg` to concatenate video files together into a single file, `video/video_after.mp4`.

I ran different tests of video length, and it seems the issue isn't correlated with the duration of the video.

When I run the following command, my terminal hangs and the operation never completes -- ss there something wrong with the command I am running here?

`ffmpeg -i video/video_after0.mp4 -i video/video_after1.mp4 -i video/video_after2.mp4 -i video/video_after3.mp4 -i video/video_after4.mp4 -i video/video_after5.mp4 -i video/video_after6.mp4 -i video/video_after7.mp4 -i video/video_after8.mp4 -i video/video_after9.mp4 -i video/video_after10.mp4 -i video/video_after11.mp4 -i video/video_after12.mp4 -i video/video_after13.mp4 -i video/video_after14.mp4 -i video/video_after15.mp4 -i video/video_after16.mp4 -i video/video_after17.mp4 -i video/video_after18.mp4 -i video/video_after19.mp4 -i video/video_after20.mp4 -f concat -safe 0 -i video/video_after21.mp4 -y -c copy video/video_after.mp4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concat demuxer only works with a text file containing a list of the videos.

So, create a text file of the form,

```
file video/video_after0.mp4
file video/video_after1.mp4
file video/video_after2.mp4
...
file video/video_after20.mp4
file video/video_after21.mp4
```

and then run

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy video/video_after.mp4
```